# Getting undefined when passing an object, but data still renders

Tags: express, ejs

I am trying to build a basic blog using Express and I am having troubles when I res.render my show page.  When I open the route in my browser the page does show as expected, but I get an error in my console that says "title is undefined".

Here's the route in question:

```
app.get("/blog/:id", function(req, res){
    Blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundBlog){
        // if(err){
        //     console.log(err);
        // } else {
            console.log(req.params.id);
            console.log(foundBlog);
            res.render("show", {blog: foundBlog});
        // }
    });
});
```

And the show.ejs that is giving me problems:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
        <h1 style="text-align: center"><%= blog.title %></h1></h1>            
        </div>

        <div style="width: 70%; margin: 25px auto;">
            <p>Written by: <%= blog.author %></p>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 70%; margin: 25px auto;">
            <p><%= blog.desc %></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="/blog/<%= blog._id %>/edit">Edit</a>
    </p>
  <a href="/blog">Back</a>  
</div>
```

And my Mongo Schema:

```
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    desc: String,
    posted: {type: Date, default: Date.now()} 
});

var Blog = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema)
```

Thanks in advance!

Previous Console.log results:

```
{ _id: 5a2341c79dd8680dc676969d,
  author: 'Jacob',
  title: 'Getting erors',
  desc: 'Why am I getting errors on the new page?',
  __v: 0,
  posted: 2017-12-03T00:13:00.609Z }
end of console
undefined
end of console
```

I now notice that when I run node app.js then my own console is doing something odd.  I am showing from the second I hit the enter key when running the app.  I have cleared out the console, yet the information displayed is starting further back.  Now neither console.log's are showing up.  This is on cloud 9 in case it matters.

```
threads13:~/workspace $ ls
JacobBlog/  README.md  client/  node_modules/  package.json  server.js
threads13:~/workspace $ cd JacobBlog/
threads13:~/workspace/JacobBlog (master) $ ls
app.js  collections data  node  node_modules/  package.json  public/  views/
threads13:~/workspace/JacobBlog (master) $ node app.js
(node:2192) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
The Jacob Blog Server Has Started!
TypeError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/JacobBlog/views/show.ejs:10
    8|     <div class="row">
    9|         <div class="container">
 >> 10|         <h1 style="text-align: center"><%= blog.title %></h1></h1>
    11|         </div>
    12|
    13|         <div style="width: 70%; margin: 25px auto;">

Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at eval (eval at compile (/home/ubuntu/workspace/JacobBlog/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:549:12), <anonymous>:22:30)
```

Found there was some sort of small mistake in my head in my HTML file that was causing this.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you try printing the `foundBlog` variable and see if it contains the `title` property?

Comment: Yes, it console.log prints the object.  I updated original post to include that and the result.

Comment: Please show your console.log statements. Why is `undefined` getting printed after `posted:...`?

Comment: Not sure why it is printing end of console twice, and undefined.

Comment: My best guess is you are making the request twice. Check your client code.

Comment: If I remove the "console.log("end of console" )" then it removes both of those statements and just leaves the undefined.

Comment: That is to be expected. I am saying that you are making request more than once it seems. You can confirm that by printing the value in `req.params.id`. Console.log it just after `app.get` line.

Comment: Please make sure your code runs properly on your machine before deploying it to cloud9.